# Mongodb $near, $geoWithin and $text

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

Initially I wanted to support mongo db text search with geo `$near` functionality. Later realized that these two cannot be used together as both require indexes.

Later I've decided to use `$geoWithin` instead. However, the results are not sorted by distance like `$near` does.

I would like to know if there is any way to sort the results returned by `$geoWithin` by 'distance'?

Comment: You cannot. Nor would it make any sense. Operators like `$near` and `$text` are meant to both basically *"find things nearest like I asked"*, in either geographically near or "like" the terms entered by relevance. These cannot be used together in one query for a number of reasons, most notably because the engine processes them differently. But it generally does not make much sense, and you acutally really want one or the other. `$geoWithin` of course does not sort, and this is by design.

Comment: More lengthy response on the related [Using full text search with geospatial index on Mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33773390/5031275). The other alternative is to run each query seperately and merge the results. But most likely you should re-evaluate exactly what you think this will do for you.

Comment: Your detailed explanation helped me to understand these concepts clearly. Thank you very much for taking your time to answer..

Answer (score 1):

The `$geoWithin` operator does not return sorted results. As a result MongoDB can return `$geoWithin` queries more quickly than geospatial `$near` or `$nearSphere` queries, which sort results. So in short use `$near` or `$nearSphere` so that you can get sorted results. see [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#unsorted-results):

> The `$geoWithin` operator does not return sorted results. As such, MongoDB can return `$geoWithin` queries more quickly than geospatial $near or `$nearSphere` queries, which sort results.

Comment: Agree with you, however I should be able to use full text search functionality with this, therefore I can't use $near or $nearSphere with $text. 

Doc says: 

You cannot combine the $near operator, which requires a special geospatial index, with a query operator or command that requires another special index. For example you cannot combine $near with the $text query.

Comment: db.places.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: 2,
        query: { type: "public" },
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        num: 5,
        spherical: true
     }
   }
])

Comment: Try Using this It looks like the aggregation framework has to be used, not find, in order to include the distance:

Please Refer this 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear

Comment: This is just a direct citation from the manual page [$geoWithin - Unsorted Results](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#unsorted-results) without actually noting it is a citation. This is not an aswer.